# upper bound of some weird function with an exponencial

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

well I'm trying to find the proof of the following statement, but I cant go forward anymore:

Let $\Omega= \mathbb{R}^{n} \times (0,\infty) $
$$w(x,t)= \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \frac{1}{(2k)!}\frac{d^kg(t)}{dt^k} ||x||^{2k} $$

where: $$g(t)=e^{-1/t^2}$$

So I need to show that there is a one point $(x^*,t^*) \in \Omega$ such that:
$$w(x^*,t^*) > Ae^{a||x||^2} \space \forall a,A>0$$

so here is what I have:

$$w(x,\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}) =  \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \frac{(-1)^ke^{-t} ||x||^{2k}}{(2k)!} $$

Hence I wish to study the following difference:
$$D_k(t)=\frac{(-1)^ke^{-t} ||x||^{2k}}{(2k)!}-\frac{Aa^k||x||^{2k}}{k!}$$

if there is a $t^*\in (0,\infty)$ such that:
$$D_k(t^*)>0 \space \forall k\in \mathbb{N}$$
then my problem will be over, but there isn't such a $t^*$. So I think I'm in the wrong way but I cannot find another. Thanks for your help.

(oh by the way this function is a solution of the heat equation but i don't think is relevant for this xD)

Comment: Well I think a need lower bound of $$D_k(t) > A_k(t)$$ 
such that $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A_k(t) = h(t)$$ and prove that there is a $t^*$ where $h(t^*)>0$

Comment: The $k$th derivative of $e^{-1/t^2}$ evaluated at $1/\sqrt{t}$ is *not* equal to the $k$th derivative of $e^{-t}$. For example $g'(t) = -\frac{2}{t^3}e^{-1/t^2}$ so $g'(1/\sqrt{t}) = -2 t^{3/2} e^{-t}$ and not $-e^{-t}$ as you have assumed.

Answer (score -1):

There inst such a $(x,t) \in \Omega$ since:
$w(x,\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}) =  \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \frac{(-1)^ke^{-t} ||x||^{2k}}{(2k)!} = e^{-t} cos(||x||) $